# Dual boot option is not popping up

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 alongside previously installed Windows 8, and it installed pretty fast an clear, but no dual boot menu is showing up,  no Grub menu is shown.

NOTE:

1. Secure boot: disabled
2. Quick boot: Off

Please advice as I don't get so as to why dual boot is not coming after startup. It just directly loads Windows 8 after HP logo.

Please help as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to re-install grub

here is some documentation on how to do so:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2